# Ehcache with defaultCache?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

In my project we are using `ehcache` for second level caching, We mentioned `<defaultCache>` tag and some `<cache>` attributes as well.

sample of **ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache>
<defaultCache
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
     maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
  />

<cache name="com.test.First"
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
  />
<cache name="com.test.Second"
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
  />
</ehcache>
```

sample of **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<class-cache class="com.test.First" usage="read-only"/>
<class-cache class="com.test.Second" usage="read-only"/>
<class-cache class="com.test.Third" usage="read-only"/>
```

here we have added `<class-cache>` tag for `com.test.Third`, which is not mentioned in `ehcache.xml` file.

Will this `com.test.Third` class also be cached by using `defaultCache`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it will for this case, because Hibernate will do the work for you. But the defaultCache is not designed for creating cache **automatically**. For more details please check this question: [Do caches in ehcache.xml inherit from defaultCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931942/do-caches-in-ehcache-xml-inherit-from-defaultcache) and this question: [EhCache default cache in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961070/ehcache-default-cache-in-java)

Comment: Thaks @Nick, but to my surprise com.test.Third also getting cached just because of <class-cache class="com.test.Third" usage="read-only"/>. Thanks.

Comment: I guess Hibernate did the creation work for you. For Hibernate 4.3.3, the getCache(String name) inside org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory will add cache programatically if it's absence. Anyway, I had adjusted my answer...